# How to Remove Burn Marks from pvc floor

Tags: repair, floor

As you can see on photos there are some burn marks. Really hot moka pot dropped down and I want remove them.What would you suggest me?

P.s.: I am actually not sure if flooring is pvc
P.s:.I thought about grinding it with sandpaper and then fill it with something

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first step is to figure out for sure what the floor is made of. Do you have any extra boxes of the material in the garage or attic? Looks like maybe linoleum tile...

Comment: I actually dont have an idea what the floor is made of but I have added another picture to my first message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, you don't. These kinds of plastic flooring materials are simply not very durable, especially to heat. But maybe you can cover it up with paint or something, after sanding or grinding down the black stain.

Comment: I just  would like to cover it however after sanding I guess there will be a hole with the deepnes 0.3 maybe 0.5 cm. So I thought about filling it with silicon then paint it with a similar color to flooring